# Create a nested list from numpy array when integer appears

Tags: python, arrays, list, data-structures, conditional-statements

I have a 1-D array of type string that looks like this:

```
["1", "---", "some text", "---", "more text", "---", "2", "---", "even more text", "---", "3", "---", "you guessed it", "---"]
```

And I want a list that is of this structure:

```
[
   ["1", "---", "some text", "---", "more text", "---"], 
   ["2", "---", "even more text", "---"], 
   ["3", "---", "you guessed it", "---"]
]
```

Apologies if my notation is wrong - again, I am quite new to data structures in Python. As you can see, each new nested list begins when a number is approached from the array.

Comment: What code have you tried so far?

Comment: Your required output is an invalid data structure (a set of sets). What exactly are you after?

Comment: Your first example is not an array, and your second example is not an list ,it is a `set` object that will throw an error since it contains other sets (which are not hashable).

Comment: please google about "lists in Python" and update your question with valid notation

Comment: In addition to looking up Python lists, I would recommend looking up Python for-loops and if-statements. Have you taken a Python course yet? I would recommend completing the entirety of the Codecademy Python track to ensure you actually understand the syntax and logic

Comment: ah, I am so new I don't know where to start. I am trying to create nested lists within a list from a 1-D array. I'll look at the notation and update.

Comment: Again, that is not an array. That isn't even valid Python syntax, but it looks most closely like a `tuple` It's going to be hard to help if we are communicating using the same words to mean different things. Programming languages, in general, remove ambiguity. Try to stick to standard Python terminology.

Comment: Since the question has been corrected and become clear, reopen it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming by "array" you mean a `list` or a `tuple`:

```
In [22]: data = ("1",
    ...: "---",
    ...: "some text",
    ...: "---",
    ...: "more text",
    ...: "---",
    ...: "2",
    ...: "---",
    ...: "even more text",
    ...: "---",
    ...: "3",
    ...: "---",
    ...: "you guessed it",
    ...: "---")
```

Then your logic should be quite straightforward:

```
In [23]: final = []

In [24]: for x in data:
    ...:     if x.isdigit():
    ...:         sub = [x]
    ...:         final.append(sub)
    ...:     else:
    ...:         sub.append(x)
    ...:

In [25]: final
Out[25]:
[['1', '---', 'some text', '---', 'more text', '---'],
 ['2', '---', 'even more text', '---'],
 ['3', '---', 'you guessed it', '---']]

In [26]:
```

Answer (score 2):

As pointed out by others, you have posted a `c` array-style desired output which in Python translates to a set of sets, which is invalid. Instead, you can create nested lists using `itertools.groupby`:

```
import itertools
s = ["1", "---", "some text", "---", "more text", "---", "2", "---", "even more text", "---", "3", "---", "you guessed it", "---"]
new_s = [list(b) for a, b in itertools.groupby(s, key=lambda x:x.isdigit())]
final_data = [new_s[i]+new_s[i+1] for i in range(0, len(new_s), 2)]
```

Output:

```
[
 ['1', '---', 'some text', '---', 'more text', '---'], 
 ['2', '---', 'even more text', '---'], 
 ['3', '---', 'you guessed it', '---']
]
```